# My time hide not working as it should

Tags: php, css

Hey im working on at time event page, where my events have to be "display: none" when the event time is over. However, where I type something like "6:45" for example, its showing op, as if the time has pass that time.

In my example, I made the "display: hidden" with a red background instead for better usage for you guys.

Hope you can help me on my way to find the error.

```js
function timeit() {
    var t = [],
        e = new Date;
    Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
        var t = this.getMonth() + 1,
            e = this.getDate();
        return [this.getFullYear(), (t > 9 ? "" : "0") + t, (e > 9 ? "" : "0") + e].join("-")
    };
    var i = e.yyyymmdd();
    if ($(".timeit").each(function() {
            function n(i) {
                var n = i - e;
                864e5 > n && n > 1e3 && t.push(n)
            }

            function a(t) {
                var e, i = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)?.(\d\d)?.(\d\d)\s*$/,
                    n = new Date(NaN);
                t.substr(0, t.indexOf(" "));
                return parts = i.exec(t), parts && (e = +parts[2], n.setFullYear(parts[1], e - 1, parts[3]), e != n.getMonth() + 1 && n.setTime(NaN), n = new Date(parts[1], e - 1, parts[3], parts[4], parts[5])), n
            }

            function r(t, n) {
                if (t) {
                    String(t).length < 6 && String(t).indexOf(":") > -1 && (t = i + " " + String(t)), -1 == String(t).indexOf(":") && (t += " 00:00");
                    var r = t.split(":"),
                        s = String(r.slice(0, 1)),
                        d = s.substr(s.length - 2),
                        o = r.slice(1),
                        l = 24 > d && 60 > o ? !0 : !1,
                        u = new Date(t);
                    if ("Invalid Date" == u) var u = a(t);
                    return "Invalid Date" != u && l || $(n).addClass("error").attr("title", '"' + t + '" date is incorrect; please use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format'), u.getTime()
                }
                return e.getTime()
            }
            var s = $(this).data("end"),
                d = $(this).data("start"),
                o = r(d, this),
                l = r(s, this);
            n(o), n(l), l > o && (o > e || e > l) || o > l && o >= e && e >= l ? $(this).addClass("hidden") : $(this).removeClass("hidden")
        }), t.length > 0) {
        var n = Math.min.apply(null, t);
        console.log("next run of timeit function is in " + n / 1e3 + "seconds"), setTimeout(function() {
            timeit()
        }, n)
    }
}
timeit();
```

```css
.hidden { 
 background: red;
}
.error {
 color: red;
}
.time {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.teams {
 padding: 3px 0;
}
.league {
 font-size: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>soccertime</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="timeit" data-start="2018-7-1 14:00" data-end="2018-7-1 15:01">
<div class="time">TV2 - 14:00</div>
<div class="teams">Spanien - Rusland</div>
<div class="league">FIFA World Cup 2018 - 1/8 finale</div>
</div>

<div class="timeit" data-start="2018-7-1 14:35" data-end="2018-7-1 16:00">
<div class="time">Youtube - 17:35</div>
<div class="teams">SK Sturm Graz - F.C. København</div>
<div class="league">Træningskamp</div>
</div>

<div class="timeit" data-start="2018-7-1 17:35" data-end="2018-7-1 19:00">
<div class="time">DR1 - 19:00</div>
<div class="teams">Kroatien - Danmark</div>
<div class="league">FIFA World Cup 2018 - 1/8 finale</div>
</div>

<div class="timeit" data-start="2018-7-1 22:50" data-end="2018-7-2 01:00">
<div class="time">Eurosport2 - 19:00</div>
<div class="teams">Toronto FC - New York Red Bulls</div>
<div class="league">Major League Soccer</div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="timeit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add jQ to your snippet, now it causes an error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: use `display: none` instead.

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek that error is only because the snippet is using a relative path to jquery, and not a full one. The snippet was not setup right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none` to hide element and also remove the element space

```
.hidden {   
    display: none !important;
}
```

While if you still need the element space then use `visibility:hidden`

```
.hidden {   
        visibility:hidden;
    }
```